# Discord bot connecting 1000 times in 24 hours

Tags: discord.js

### UPDATE: Turns out the problem (I and a friend think) is the way my (now former) bot host connected to Discord.  So I'm trying a new host to see if it helps...

This is the first time I've had to break down and ask a question... I have a simple bot that   reads a file and returns a random line from it.  It was working just fine until recently, when it started getting shut down by Discord.  I get this error:

> It appears your bot, x, has connected to Discord more than 1000 times within a short time period. Since this kind of behavior is usually a result of a bug we have gone ahead and reset your bot's token.

Here's my code.  Thanks for any help you can give.

```js
// Require stuff, declare stuff
const Discord = require("./node_modules/discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");
var http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
var err = '';
var data = '';

// This section lifted from https://gist.github.com/eslachance

client.on("ready", () => {
    // This event will run if the bot starts, and logs in, successfully.
    console.log(`Bot has started, serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`);
    client.user.setActivity(`command`);
}, (err, data));

client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    // This event triggers when the bot joins a guild.
    console.log(`New guild joined: ${guild.name} . This guild has ${guild.memberCount} members!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`command`);
}, (err, data));

client.on("guildDelete", guild => {
    // this event triggers when the bot is removed from a guild.
    console.log(`I have been removed from: ${guild.name} .`);
    client.user.setActivity(`command`);
}, (err, data));


client.on("message", async message => {

    try {
 
        // This event will run on every single message received, from any channel or DM.

        if (!msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

        // And now, my part!

        // Read in the file of cat jokes and make it an array
        fs.readFile('textfile.txt', function(err, data) {
            if(err) throw err;
            const content = data.toString();
            const allLines = content.split("\n");
            var linenum = Math.floor(Math.random() * allLines.length);
                
            // Reply to the command with the random joke
            message.channel.send(allLines[linenum]);      

        });

    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error caught');
    }

}, (err, data));

client.login(config.token);
```

The most recent error in the log is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ClientDataManager.newChannel (/root/chester/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81:36)
    at Guild.setup (/root/chester/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:307:68)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (/root/chester/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildCreate.js:12:15)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/root/chester/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/root/chester/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/root/chester/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/root/chester/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/root/chester/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: Did you read this https://github.com/cameroncros/OctoPrint-DiscordRemote/issues/10

Comment: I did, and I'm not sure what to do about it considering people were still having issues.

Comment: Did you read the whole discussion .. No Answers .. But I noticed they closed issue and opened it again times means the Issues still not resolved yet .. I recommend to add your problem to this issue as may anyone faced same issue and resolved it :)

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you have "logged in" to your bot too many times in 24 hours. This occurs when you run your bot 1000 times in 24 hours. To fix this error, go to the discord developer portal, and regenerate your bot's token, and paste the new token into your code.

Comment: I tried that first thing when the problem started.  It just had the same problem all over again.  Thanks, though.

Comment: are you using an online ide to run your bot? your ide might be the reason

Comment: check if vultr has an option to toggle that has similar phrasing to "run after each keystroke", if it does, disable it